# How can I code a factory in Perl and Moose?

Tags: perl, factory, moose

Is there a simpler or better (=>easier to maintain) way to use Perl and [`Moose`](http://moose.perl.org/) to instantiate classes based on incoming data?

The following code is a stripped down sample from a project I'm working on.

```
package FooBar;
use Moose;
has 'SUBCLASS' =>('isa'=>'Str',required=>'1',is=>'ro');
has 'MSG' =>('isa'=>'Str',required=>'1',is=>'ro');

sub BUILD {
      my $self = shift;
      my ($a)=@_;
      bless($self,$a->{SUBCLASS})
}
sub Hi {
   my $self=shift;
   print "Hi, I'm a " . ref($self)  ." and I say [". $self->MSG()."]\n";
}

package Foo;
use Moose;
extends ("FooBar");

package Bar;
use Moose;
extends ("FooBar");

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $line (<DATA>) {
   my ($case,$msg)=split(/[\n\r,]\s*/,$line);
   FooBar->new(SUBCLASS=>$case,MSG=>$msg)->Hi();
}
```

```
__DATA__
Foo, First Case
Bar, Second Case
```

**EDIT**: It just struck me that this is pretty much what happens when you call the DBI. Depending on the parameters you pass, it will use entirely different code while maintaining a (mostly) consistent interface

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ick. Stevan has a very compelling argument that `new` should always only
return an instance of Class. Anything else is confusing to new people learning
the system.

You might wanna take a look at
[MooseX::AbstractFactory](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-AbstractFactory/).
If that won't work for you then:

```
package FooBar;
use Moose;

has [qw(SUBCLASS MSG)] => ( is => 'ro', required => 1);

sub create_instance {
    return $self->package->new(message => $self->msg);
}

package FooBar::Object;
use Moose;

has msg => ( is => 'ro', required => 1);

sub Hi {
   my $self = shift;
   print "Hi, I'm a " . ref($self)  ." and I say [". $self->MSG()."]\n";
}

package Foo;
use Moose;
extends qw(FooBar::Object);

package Bar;
use Moose;
extends qw(FooBar::Object);


package main;
or my $line (<DATA>) {
   my ($case,$msg)=split(/[\n\r,]\s*/,$line);
   FooBar->new(SUBCLASS=>$case,MSG=>$msg)->create_instance->Hi
}

__DATA__
Foo, First Case
Bar, Second Case
```

Of course there are many other ways to implement this same concept in Moose. Without knowing the specifics of your domain problem it's hard to tell that something like [MooseX::Traits](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Traits) wouldn't be better:

```
package Foo;
use Moose;
with qw(MooseX::Traits);

package Bar;
use Moose;
with qw(MooseX::Traits);

package Messaging;
use Moose::Role;

has msg => ( is => 'ro', required => 1);

sub Hi {
   my $self = shift;
   print "Hi, I'm a " . ref($self)  ." and I say [". $self->MSG()."]\n";
}

package main;
use strict;
Foo->with_traits('Messaging')->new( msg => 'First Case')->Hi;
```

This is roughly what the other poster meant about using a Role based solution.

Comment: **has [qw(SUBCLASS MSG)] => ( is => 'ro', required => 1);** neat trick .. but "unintuitive" for anyone not familiar with perl ..

Comment: No it's not.  It is part of the Moose API and has nothing to do with Perl.  (If you wanted to be unintuitive, you would write "has $_ => (...) for qw/SUBCLASS MSG/".  But of course, everyone knows what this does too.)

Comment: I think it's safe to assume anybody who's reading a question about Moose either is familiar with Perl or wishes to be. That syntax is documented in Moose.pm and they're free to ask about it.

Answer (score 6):

You could simply do:

```
$case->new( MSG => $msg )->Hi();
```

If that is easier or better is up to you to decide.

Comment: using a variable as the class to be instantiated **$case->new(..)** in that way feels very strange. But yes, extremely compact, when compared to my code (where I spell it out **bless( {} ,$case)** 
 
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: why is that strange? a class name in Perl is just a string. Foo->blah is exactly the same as "Foo"->blah.

Comment: If there's no logic in the factory to choose the correct subclass to instantiate then its not much of a factory and this is by a wide margin the best solution.

Comment: My original code (too long to post, so I stripped it down to the sample above) does a DB query and uses some logic do derive the class that needs to be instantiated. I want to encapsulate that in a factory.

Answer (score 5):

Just a note on some of the answers:

Calling `bless` in BUILD, or anywhere outside of the MOP internals, is always unacceptable.  (If you must rebless, there is `Class::MOP::Class->rebless_instance`!)

I second the advice on not allowing `new` to return anything other than an instance of `__PACKAGE__`.  If you want a method that creates an instance of something, call it something else.  Example:

```
class Message {
   method new_from_string(Str $msg){
       my ($foo, $bar, $baz) = ($msg =~ /<...>/); # blah blah blah
       my $class = "Message::${foo}::$baz";
       Class::MOP::load_class($class);
       return $class->new( bar => $msg );
   }
}
```

Then, when you want to create a literal message:

```
Message->new( whatever => 'you want' );
```

When you want to parse a string and return the correct message subclass:

```
Message->new_from_string( 'OH::Hello!' );
```

Finally, if it doesn't make sense to be able to create an instance of Message, then it should not be a class.  It should be a role.

You can handle building with some other object, of course.  Just make sure this other object is responsible only for understanding the string format, for example, and not message internals:

```
class MessageString {
    has 'string' => ( initarg => 'string', reader => 'message_as_string' );

    method new_from_string(ClassName $class: Str $string) {
        return $class->new( string => $string );
    }

    method as_message_object {
        # <parse>
        return Message::Type->new( params => 'go here', ... );
    }
}

role Message { ... }
class Message::Type with Message { ... }
```

Now you are no longer concerned with having some "superclass" responsible for building "subclasses", which I think is better design.  (Remember, MessageString has no special power over the classes that do "Message".  That is the key here; it is only responsible for understanding stringified messages.)

Anyway, now you just:

```
my $data =  <>; # Yup, I called it $data.  Sorry, Andy Lester.
my $parsed = MessageString->new_from_string( $data );
my $message = $parsed->as_message_object;
$message->interact_with
```

(You know "MVC"?  This is similar.)

Answer (score 4):

Just use another factory object to construct objects of that class.

Simpler, more flexible, more reliable, etc.

`my $factory = Factory->new( ... factory parameters ... );`

my $object = $factory->new_object( ... various parameters ... );

where `new_object` can parse the parameters and make decisions on both data inside `$factory` and data from those parameters.

When you figure out that you'll need codependent objects in the next step, look for an inversion of control framework.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the object is already created when `BUILD` is called, so I would say

```
sub BUILD {
      my $self = shift;
      return bless $self, $self->SUBCLASS;
}
```

You may always wish to switch from an inheritance based model to a role based model where you create the object you want (rather than passing the class into the factory class), then apply the common role.

Comment: Where would you send me to learn/understand the transition of " inheritance based" to "role based"?

Comment: The Moose Manual on Roles would be a start http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Manual::Roles

Comment: `BUILD` just throw out returned value